# Can I extend my Netherlands Resident Permit while being on notice period?

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, netherlands, skilled-migration

I hold a Netherlands Resident Permit (RP - High Skilled Migrant) and I am about to switch to another company here (IND registered). But I would have to serve a notice period of 3 months at my current company. My new company would take care of the RP extension, but is it possible to do this while serving the notice period at my current company?